# Zip all files in a directory individually and password protect them.

Tags: zip

I'm using an Ubuntu system to download suspicious/suspected malware files for analysis.  I need to zip each file and password protect it to prevent accidentally infecting other systems when transferring the files. the

Answer (score 0):

You have two options with [`zip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/zip.1.html):

> ```
>   -e
>   --encrypt
>           Encrypt  the  contents of the zip archive using a password which
>           is entered on the terminal in response to a  prompt  (this  will
>           not  be  echoed;  if  standard error is not a tty, zip will exit
>           with an error).  The password prompt is  repeated  to  save  the
>           user from typing errors.
>   -P password
>   --password password
>           Use password to encrypt  zipfile  entries  (if  any).   THIS  IS
>           INSECURE!   Many  multi-user  operating systems provide ways for
>           any user to see the current command line of any other user; even
>           on  stand-alone  systems there is always the threat of over-the-
>           shoulder peeking.  Storing the plaintext password as part  of  a
>           command  line  in  an  automated script is even worse.  Whenever
>           possible, use  the  non-echoing,  interactive  prompt  to  enter
>           passwords.   (And  where security is truly important, use strong
>           encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively
>           weak standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.)
> ```

So if you really wish to script this, you'll need to use `-P`, since `-e` forces the manual entry of passwords. Do so only if you are the only user in your environment, or if `/proc` was mounted with appropriate permissions (even then root will be able to see the password).
This command should do the trick:

```
cd <path_to_directory>
find . -type f -printf "../%f.zip\0%f\0" | xargs -0n 2 zip -P pass
```

This will create zip files of each file, with the same name as that file (i.e., `blah.doc` will create `blah.doc.zip`) in the parent directory, each protected by the password `pass`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This script works but, it puts the zip file in a directory above the one that it was run under. So if the files are located in Downloads the resulting zip files are now located under Home.

Comment: @porkfatist yes. I did say it will create zip files in *the parent directory*. The other way would be to generate a list of files first and then read from that list to zip. I'm sure you can modify the script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**This may not be exactly what you wanted; I wasn't quite sure what you meant?** My code assumes 3 things: you only have 1 file (or set of files) you wish to place into a single archive, you save the virus file in your user's "Downloads" folder, and you have created a folder called "Viruses" in your user's home folder that contains a sub-folder called "Saved"; this is where the finished file will be.

Upon running the command the virus file will be put into a password protected .zip archive (you will be prompted to pick a password), moved to the "Viruses" folder and renamed virus.zip, and then moved to the "Viruses/Saved" folder. **The original virus file will be deleted from "Downloads" (as well as anything else you have in that folder!!!).**

When you download another virus, and run the command again. The current "virus.zip" will be named "virus.zip~1~" and the new file will be named virus.zip. If you run the command again the current "virus.zip" will be named "virus.zip~1~", the current "virus.zip~1~" will be named "virus.zip~2~", and the new virus archive will be named virus.zip. This will happen everytime you run the command.

To see these files you will need to allow showing hidden files. To open them just rename the extension to .zip.

You can run the command as many times as you need. As mentioned before this is only if you are downloading the files 1 at a time, or they will all be put in a single archive.

**Steps:**

1. Download a virus
2. Run this command :

   `cd ~/Downloads && zip -e -0  Downloads * && mv *.zip ~/Viruses/virus.zip && rm * && mv --backup=t ~/Viruses/virus.zip ~/Viruses/Saved/virus.zip`
3. Repeat